# I am not able to update my entity table (Spring Boot 2 hibernate 5)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 2.1.2, Hibernate 5 and mysql 5.7.25. And hibernate  is coming from spring data-jpa. I can insert the data into the entity table. But the issues is with update operation. When i try to update the entity, its not working. I cannot find out issue. Someone please help me to sort out the issue.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>A service application.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Property File

```
# Application running port
server.port=8000

# Application running port
server.servlet.contextPath=/

# Log files
logging.level.org.springframework.web: ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR

#DB config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_app
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#DB pool config
# Maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection from connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000 
# Minimum number of idle connections
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
# Maximum pool size
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
# Maximum amount of time in milliseconds that a connection is allowed to sit idle
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=900000 
# Maximum life time in milliseconds of a connection in pool after it is closed
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=10000
# auto-commit behavior of connections returned from pool
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true 

# Hibernayte config
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# toenable transaction
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

Entity Class

```
package com.app.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user_account")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Integer active;

    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
    private Calendar createdDate;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Integer createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Calendar updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Integer updatedBy;

    public Integer getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Integer createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Integer getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Integer updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public UserAccount() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Calendar getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Calendar createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Calendar getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Calendar updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

}
```

DAO Interface

```
package com.app.dao;

public interface UserAccountDao {

    void saveAndUpdate();

}
```

DAOImpl

```
 package com.app.daoImpl;

    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.app.dao.UserAccountDao;
    import com.app.model.UserAccount;

    @Repository("UserAccountDao")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public class UserAccountDaoImpl implements UserAccountDao {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Autowired
        private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

        public Session getSession() {
            return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
        }


        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void saveAndUpdate() {
            Session session = getSession();
            UserAccount userAccount =new UserAccount("Test@1235", "Test@1234", 1, Calendar.getInstance(), 1);
            session.save(userAccount);
            userAccount.setPassword("new password");
            session.saveOrUpdate(userAccount);
        }

    }
```

Service Interface

```
     package com.app.service;

public interface UserAccountService {
    void saveAndUpdateUserData();
}
```

Service Class

```
     package com.app.serviceImpl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.app.dao.UserAccountDao;
import com.app.service.UserAccountService;

@Service("UserAccountService")
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserAccountServiceImpl implements UserAccountService {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountDao userAccountDao;

    @Override
    public void saveAndUpdateUserData() {
        userAccountDao.saveAndUpdate();

    }



}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.app.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.service.UserAccountService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
UserAccountService userAccountService;


    @GetMapping()
    public String addUser() {

        userAccountService.saveAndUpdateUserData();
        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Nothing, it didn't showing any error.

Comment: And not even showing the update query. Is there any mistake in my configuration

Comment: Not showing any update query..

Comment: where is your service class code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess as you are doing `save` and `saveOrUpdate` concurrently that is causing the issue. Either, you should first close/flush the session via `session.close()` and then begin a new transaction for update.

Similar to like a sql query if its still processing although executed we use commit as to ensure the final changes have been made and are in existence and then we move to another transaction.

Comment: If any error happened in the second operation i want to roll back 1st operation.  For that purpose i mentioned @Transactional annotation in the method. If I close the session after 1st operation will roll back work?

Answer (score 0):

You made your program over-complex. With spring boot you don't need to implement dao class by yourself.
All you need to do is extending your dao from `JpaRepository`.

dao:

```
public interface UserAccountDao extends JpaRepository<UserAccount , Integer> {
}
```

service:

```
@service
public UserAccountService{
  @Autowired private UserAccountDao dao;

  public UserAcount saveAndUpdateUserData(UserAccount newAccount) {
    return dao.saveAndFlush(newAccount);
  }
}
```

controller:

```
@controller
public class TestController {
  @Autowired
  private UserAccountService userAccountService;

  @PostMapping("/test")
  public String addUser(UserAccount newAccount) {
      userAccountService.saveAndUpdateUserData(newAccount);
      return "Success";
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to use JPA .That is why i implement Hibernate Configuration